# How to find dead tuples size in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

How to find dead tuples size in postgresql ?
I have created backup of database using pg_dump and restored it  on other server. I see there is database size difference (5 GB)in both database. I have verified the table live tuples and dead tuples. There is numbers of row difference due to new data added in current database. However it is big difference in restored DB size. What is the cause  of it ? I didn't do vacuum analyze on restored database yet.

I see there is no dead tuples on restored database this may be one reason. That's why I want to find deadtuples size.

Comment: As I understand after Vacuum dead tuples are removed and space can be used by table for new rows. So there is some free space is available in table.  While restoring database new table is created and data are copied into it from dump. so restored database does not have extra free space allocated.  This can be reason of db size difference in actual DB and restored DB.

Comment: Total n_livetuples and select count(1) from tablename  has difference. why any idea?

Answer (score 14):

This is the view that you need to check:

```
select n_live_tup, n_dead_tup, relname from pg_stat_all_tables;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the extension [pgstattuple](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstattuple.html).  It will report dead_tuple_len.

Comment: Do you have an example for this please? I have a database `master_db`, which has a schema called `radius`.  How do I check all tables inside that schema?